# Broken pipe error on query from aerospike

Tags: aerospike

i have namespace "test" and set "demo"
when i run "select * from test.demo" in aql terminal, i got this error. What exactly causes broken pipe?

[image]

and i got a warn message in server log below.

[image: server log]

and my aerospike.conf is:

```
service {
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
    proto-fd-max 15000
}

logging {
    file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
            context any info
    }
}

network {
    service {
            address any
            port 3000
    }

    heartbeat {
            mode multicast
            multicast-group 239.1.99.222
            port 9918

            # To use unicast-mesh heartbeats, remove the 3 lines above, and see
            # aerospike_mesh.conf for alternative.

            interval 150
            timeout 10
    }

    fabric {
            port 3001
    }

    info {
            port 3003
    }
}

namespace test {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 4G
    default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.

    storage-engine memory
}
namespace bar {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 4G
    default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.

    storage-engine memory

    # To use file storage backing, comment out the line above and use the
    # following lines instead.
    #       storage-engine device {
    #               file /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat
    #               filesize 16G
    #               data-in-memory true # Store data in memory in addition to file.
    #       }
}
```

somebody can figure out the reason?

Comment: aql uses C client underneath. Error -10 in C client is: AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Synchronous connection error. Socket read error 11: resource temporarily unavailable - wonder why that is happening.

Comment: Anything interesting in the server logs maybe?

Comment: @Meher，hi Meher, i just got a warn in server logs like below.
Apr 12 2018 06:07:58 GMT: WARNING (proto): (proto.c:693) send error - fd 29 Broken pipe

Comment: Wha't the timeout that you have set in aql?

Comment: @Darian.miao is it possible you do have a lot of records in your namespace that do not have any set associated with them? This would slow down the scan you are issuing and would then cause the client to timeout. But if you really just have those 2 records in those 2 sets, than I am not sure what could be causing this... can you show the total number of records you have in the namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting a socket error when trying to send the scan result to a  socket that has already timedout on the client side.

```
Error: (-10) Socket read error: 11, [::1]:3000, 36006
```

By default the aql timeout is set to 1000ms

It could be bumped up to 100000ms using the -T command line option. (or using set timeout within the aql interactive mode)

```
aql -T 100000
```

**`-T, --timeout <ms>   Set the timeout (ms) for commands. Default: 1000`**
This option is equivalent to setting TotalTimeout on [other clients](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/understanding-timeout-and-retry-policies/2852).

Setting the timeout higher should help, but doesn't answer why a basic scan would take so long.

Here is an example with setting different client timeouts, this shows the clients timing out prior to the scan result being received. In the logs you would see the TCP send error for scan.

```
WARNING (proto): (proto.c:693) send error - fd 32 Broken pipe
```

Details from aql console:

```
aql> set timeout 10
TIMEOUT = 10
aql> select * from test.demo
Error: (-10) Socket read error: 11, 127.0.0.1:3000, 58496

aql> select * from test.demo
Error: (-10) Socket read error: 115, 127.0.0.1:3000, 58498


aql> set timeout 100
TIMEOUT = 100
aql> select * from test.demo
Error: (-10) Socket read error: 115, 127.0.0.1:3000, 58492

aql> set timeout 1000
TIMEOUT = 1000
aql> select * from test.demo
+-----+-------+
| foo | bar   |
+-----+-------+
| 123 | "abc" |
+-----+-------+
1 row in set (0.341 secs)
```

Its still a mystery why your aql client would timeout for returning 1  record, if default timeout was kept at 1000ms. Did you by any chance modify the timeout. Or have a huge number of records in the test namespace with null sets.

Comment: AQL is an interactive C application. The AQL timeout is just to limit the output to AQL should you do a "select * ... " on a huge dataset.  I would think changing the timeout will not solve this problem...but lets see.